# JWT authentication and forwarding using AWS API Gateway

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, jwt

I require to develop an authentication module. So far I have a DynamoDB and some endpoints to register users. The next step is to set some API Gateway endpoints to receive a JWT, validate it and, if ok, forward the request to another endpoint.

My problem is that I want to develop this using code, something like Serverless or SAM. Right now I am using the AWS web console, however this will become hard to manage as more endpoints are added. I would like to have some version control and deploy capabilities using code.

In short. I require an api with a JWT custom authorizer which, if approved, forwards the request to another endpoint which will in turn process the request and return a response.

Any ideas on how can I accomplish this without using the web console?

Comment: you may need to post this on stackexchange. other than that, are you asking how to deploy without using AWS console, If yes, you can setup IAM credentials and deploy from a CICD tool such as teamcity, circleci, bamboo etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the serverless framework.

You need to define a lambda that will be your custom authorizer.  Then you can use the following  configuration https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: posts.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: posts/create
          method: post
          authorizer:
            name: authorizerFunc
            resultTtlInSeconds: 0
            identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
            identityValidationExpression: someRegex
            type: token
  authorizerFunc:
    handler: handler.authorizerFunc
```